# Close activities after clicking a button inside a Dialog in c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have 3 activities:
A -> B -> C
When I'm in "C" I can go back to edit some values if I want, but after click a button in C it shows me a Dialog with a button that it says something like "Okay, you did good, your data is processing now". After clicking the button inside the dialog I want to close A, B and C. 
I've read about `NoHistory` and applying that, I can't go back to edit the values, so I can't use it in this case. 
What should I do? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up your intent to launch a new activity by pressing the confirmation button, set these intent flags before calling `startActivity()`:

```
yourIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

These flags force the associated activity task to be cleared, and start a new task with this intent. More on Intent flags can be found in the Android Developers documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html.

Comment: I have to put `intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);` and it works great :) Thank you!